# libtar.h on mingw32

Tags: c++, mingw, tar

is there a way to use tar.h/libtar.h on MinGW? Compiling libtar fails with an error that it needs tar.h - And tar isn't even compiling because it needs some defines that it only has on unix (I assume.. crashes in rtapelib.c -> SIGPIPE).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my experience libtar simply won't work under Windows, since (as you say) it depends on some Unix-isms.  On the other hand, the .tar format ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format) ) isn't very complicated, so if you need to you can write your own .tar reading and/or writing code with only a small amount of effort.  In my case I needed to only write out a .tar file, not read it, and my TarFileWriter class ( https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/zlib/TarFileWriter.cpp ) ended up being just 146 lines long.

Comment: @Jeremy please don't post code without the license, as we can't tell whether it can be used.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi from https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/zlib/zlib/README looks like 3-clause BSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/gnulib.html#tar_002eh

Portability problems not fixed by Gnulib:

```
This header file is missing on some platforms: Cygwin, mingw, MSVC 9, BeOS.
```